# Do a process after FlatMap complete all requests

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using RxJs `6.1.0` in Angular 6 to get data from multiple observables as below:

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.subscribeInit = this.tradingService.getInProgress()
  .do((s) => {
    this.keys = s.map((tdi)=> tdi.key);
    return this.keys;
  })
  .flatMap((key)=>this.tradingService.getTradingData(key))
  .subscribe((res)=>{        
    this.formattedData.push(res);
  });
}
```

I want to do a process after all observables have completed execution from `flatMap` i.e all data is pushed to `formattedData`.

Please guide me know how can I achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just add the `complete` handler to `subscribe()`:

```
...
.subscribe(
  res => ...,
  undefined,
  () => /* completed */
)
```

You you can use so-called "partial observer" object:

```
...
.subscribe({
  next: res => ...,
  complete: () => /* completed */,
})
```

Comment: Works thanks! Could you also help me how to catch errors and move on with the remaining requests during flatMap exec?